# bootstrap-typeahead.js fetch json from a file or remote source

Tags: python, json, twitter-bootstrap, flask, bootstrap-typeahead

Hello Guys I am using bootstrap-typeahead.js to fetch the json data of all users list in my flask project.

As per the basic Behaviour of Bootstrap Type ahead I am able to view specified json data under the type ahead calling function but not getting how to get json data.

This snippet will take the JSON list of cities and then shows pretty well using typeahead

```
<p>Type Query: <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" id="cities" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" ></input></p>

<script type="text/javascript"></script>
$('#cities').typeahead({
    source: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Toronto' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Montreal' },
        { id: 3, name: 'New York' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Buffalo' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Boston' },
        { id: 6, name: 'Columbus' },
        { id: 7, name: 'Dallas' },
        { id: 8, name: 'Vancouver' },
        { id: 9, name: 'Seattle' },
        { id: 10, name: 'Los Angeles' }
    ]

    });
```

But when I want to get data from remote source or from file that should be something like this as per this [twitter-bootstrap-typeahead](https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead)

```
$('#cities').typeahead({
    ajax: '/sample/list'
});
```

but This is not working as per my requirements.

I have this view to fetch all the users in Python Flask

```
@app.route('/users')
@login_required
def get_all_users():
  all_users =  model.User.query()
  first = {}; users = []
  for user in all_users:
    user_key = user.key
    first['uname'] = user.name
    first['uuid'] = user_key.integer_id()
    first['about_me'] = user.about_me
    first['email'] = user.email
    users.append(first)
    first = {}
  return jsonify(users=users)
```

and it throws data which is something like this

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "about_me": null, 
      "email": "chitrankdixit@gmail.com", 
      "uname": "Chitrank", 
      "uuid": 5066549580791808
    }, 
    {
      "about_me": null, 
      "email": "test@example.com", 
      "uname": "Test", 
      "uuid": 5629499534213120
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I am completely confused that why typeahead is not taking JSON data from my flask view. Please help